# concatenation of two models feature vector for fusion

Tags: python-3.x

I've trained two models on **VGG16** both models are trained on a different dataset.
I want to concatenate these two models for predicting new image.
So,**My query is how can i concatenate these two models**.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO ! Could you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: Hello, I have trained two models such as first one is VGG16model1.h5 and the second one is VGG16model2.h5 now i just want to do is to concatenate these two model's feature vector into one and make prediction on new images.